# linux/ubuntu os that follows Tails/Tor ideals

Tags: security, encryption

I am a new ubuntu user, So forgive me if I sound stupid, In my head my question sounds like it could work. so my question has 2 parts.

1. Is there already a OS that can have just a basic file system something like a NAS, That could hold user data with a folder for user pref and settings, Then all the apps, scripts, programs ect, that are targets for attack can uninstall/reinstall, at the beginning or end of a user session?
2. could it be done and worth the work?

my idea is that you would have a basic file system os that hold all your data and files, Then have a extra encrypted folder/program that holds a back up list off all pref, programs, config, ect. When you log into a session all of the programs that reinstalled take a number in priority and reconfig everything like nothing happened. It wouldn't take to much time to load its mainly web browsers and a few others.

So if you did have some virus, malware,forced downloads, back doors, ect, At the end of your session your programs and their files "go back to factory codition". so any attack would be deleted, The pc would have great encryption and everything that stays on the pc gets checked and approved by you. when you download something from the web it would go in a temp Downloads folder that was cut off from the file system, until  it went through your verification process.

I am not a power user of pc's, I mainly torrent movies and the biggest step I have ever taken was installing 16.04 and Kodi on 2 pc's. So please forgive my stupidity and Thanks for your time.   All feedback is good feedback!

Comment: have you tried Kali Live CD?

Comment: ive looked into it, ubuntu is a happy mid way point between windows and linux. i get to hot headed at times and i would prob break my set up using terminal all the time. i like ubuntu because of the gui and the freedom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This OS exists and its name is [Trusted End Node Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Portable_Security) (TENS). TENS, previously called Lightweight Portable Security (LPS), is a Linux security distribution that runs entirely from RAM when it is booted from a bootable USB flash drive. TENS Public turns an untrusted system (such as a home computer) into a trusted network client. No trace of work activity (or malware) can be written to the local computer hard drive.

Because you can't write anything more than web browser bookmarks to the TENS USB drive, you can't use TENS for hacking or anything like that.

[image: TENS]

Comment: could it be reprogrammed to act as a dedicated os? use partitioning on the drive to keep temp folders from the trusted folders? The bridge between the 2 file systems could be programming to use check sums and verification before anything is moved to the trusted side?

Comment: Definitely not because LPS is locked down 100%. As its name suggests, LPS is designed for *personal* security, not to be customized or modified in any way.

Comment: i understand now, i missed that. I'm less concerned about hiding and just thinking about a logical way to stop attackers in their tracks. thanks for the answer!